How to send a status code on RESTful controller api without an error?

VM1411:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'O', "OK" is not valid JSON

When I fetch JSON(stringified object) data to the server and try to send a statusCode number 200 for indicating its status as OK in order to response, the client webpage keeps receiving that error for unknown reason. The server "can" take the JSON from the client-side, but only retrieving does not working right now. How to send the status code without getting an error?
client/js/product/index.js
var lotion = {
    name: "Vaseline",
    price: 20,
    skinProtection: true,
    protectionLevel: 10
};

class Order {
    constructor(method, target) {
        this.method = method;
        this.target = target;
        this.serve();
    }
    options(method, target) {
        return {
            method: method,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(target)
        }
    }
    readAPI(path) {
        return fetch(`http://localhost:3500/controllers/product/${path}`, this.options(this.method, this.target))
    }
    async serve() {
       let receive = await (await this.readAPI('order')).json();
       console.log(receive);
    }
}

let getOrder = new Order('post', lotion)

server/app/controllers/index.js
const express = require('express');
const controllers = express.Router();

controllers.post('/product/order', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200); // This causes that the browser receives an error
})

module.exports = controllers; // all the name must be matched

server/app/app.js
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const controllers = require('./controllers/index.js');
app.use('/controllers', controllers)

module.exports = app;

server/index.js
const app = require('./app/app.js');

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`port: ${process.env.PORT}`);
})

File structure diagram
.
├── client/
│   ├── js/
│   │   ├── index/
│   │   └── product/
│   │       └── index.js
│   └── pages/
│       ├── index.html
│       └── product.html
└── server/
    ├── app/
    │   ├── controllers/
    │   │   └── index.js
    │   └── app.js
    ├── .env
    ├── node_modules
    ├── index.js
    ├── package-lock.json
    └── package.json

Attempts

Added `"Accept": "application/json" to as a headers' property.
Added .json({message: "OK"}) on res.sendStatus(200).


In your controlle, I don't see you actually setting a body. Perhaps express is defaulting to a (string) body of the HTTP status when no body is set.

@Evert Could you explain more detail? Does that mean I have to use body-parser module on the post api?

No the error happens because your client is trying to parse JSON that is returned from the server. You never set a response body. body-parser is for parsing request bodies.
If you don't care about this, don't call .json() on the client.

@Evert Oh you are saying I was supposed to use.then() method which takes a response callback. I see. Thanks for your comments.

You said you are getting the error on the client webpage, right? It would be interesting if you could share how you are consuming this post endpoint in your client application, but I think the problem is that you are trying to transform the response from the endpoint into a JSON, and the sendStatus method only sends an "OK" string, which cannot be converted to JSON. You can try using:
.status(200).send({ status: "success" }), for example!
Or just don't use .json() in your client. Hope this helps!

I've just returned to the development field after long time break and was completely getting confused between send(), sendStatus() and status(). Thank you for your answer. This helps me to remind a lot of things.

Glad that it helped you, @lagunayellow. Welcome back and let's rock!!
